# How to create a table that fits over the page and has text centered?

Tags: tables, longtable, page, physics

I'm trying to recreate the following table. I've only worked with `booktabs` before so I don't know how to create this kind of table.

[image]

This is what I tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Controlled Variable & Description & Value \\ \hline
                    &             &       \\ \hline
                    &             &       \\ \hline
                    &             &       \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.tablesgenerator.com/

Comment: You can combine a p{width} column with \centering, or create a new column type using the array package.